# Optimizing Disk I/O Performance in Linux: Advanced Techniques for High Throughput and Low Latency

Tags: linux

I'm currently working on a Linux-based server with high disk I/O demands, and I'm looking for advanced strategies to fine-tune the system for optimal performance. While I've implemented basic optimizations, I'm seeking insights into deeper, more specialized techniques.

Specifically, I'd like to know:

- What are some advanced kernel-level configurations and tuning parameters that can significantly improve disk I/O performance on Linux? How can I leverage features like the I/O scheduler, file system tuning, and block device settings?
- Are there any specialized file systems or storage solutions that excel in high I/O environments, and what considerations should be taken when choosing or configuring them?
- How can I effectively monitor and analyze disk I/O performance to identify bottlenecks or areas for improvement? Are there specific tools or utilities that provide deep insights into I/O operations?
- What are some advanced caching and buffering strategies that can be implemented to reduce disk I/O latency and increase throughput, especially for frequently accessed data?
- Are there any best practices for optimizing I/O-bound applications or workloads, such as databases or high-throughput web servers, to make the most of available disk resources?

Answer (score 0):

In Redhat, there is `tuned`.  And from RHEL 7.9 a `tuned-adm list` shows

```
Available profiles:
- atomic-guest                - Optimize virtual guests based on the Atomic variant
- atomic-host                 - Optimize bare metal systems running the Atomic variant
- balanced                    - General non-specialized tuned profile
- cpu-partitioning            - Optimize for CPU partitioning
- default                     - Legacy default tuned profile
- desktop                     - Optimize for the desktop use-case
- desktop-powersave           - Optmize for the desktop use-case with power saving
- enterprise-storage          - Legacy profile for RHEL6, for RHEL7, please use throughput-performance profile
- hpc-compute                 - Optimize for HPC compute workloads
- laptop-ac-powersave         - Optimize for laptop with power savings
- laptop-battery-powersave    - Optimize laptop profile with more aggressive power saving
- latency-performance         - Optimize for deterministic performance at the cost of increased power consumption
- mssql                       - Optimize for MS SQL Server
- network-latency             - Optimize for deterministic performance at the cost of increased power consumption, focused on low latency network performance
- network-throughput          - Optimize for streaming network throughput, generally only necessary on older CPUs or 40G+ networks
- oracle                      - Optimize for Oracle RDBMS
- powersave                   - Optimize for low power consumption
- server-powersave            - Optimize for server power savings
- spindown-disk               - Optimize for power saving by spinning-down rotational disks
- throughput-performance      - Broadly applicable tuning that provides excellent performance across a variety of common server workloads
- virtual-guest               - Optimize for running inside a virtual guest
- virtual-host                - Optimize for running KVM guests
```

I would research into `tuned` into what they are doing for profiles such as `enterprise storage` along with any of the other ones that seem relevant.  You would not want to have such things done by the `spindown-disk` profile happening... I would think... or any kind of power saving stuff.

Unless you have I/O happening that exceeds RAM capacity of the system, 768gb being the norm of 4 socket high end servers and ~128gb of not-too-expensive workstations, the optimal way to do it would be creating a `tmpfs` mounted as a `/data` folder so that you are reading/writing directly from [DDR4 or DDR5] RAM, and then manage that volatile data location accordingly.  Would be a matter of doing in `/etc/fstab` something like `tmpfs  /data  tmpfs  defaults,size=512G  0  0`.  I wouldn't call it *an advanced buffering strategy*, but making use of RAM exclusively instead of disk at SATA/SAS speeds of 6 Gbit/s or 12 Gbit/s will be orders of magnitude faster, as well as something I don't think you have to *tune* linux for other than simply doing an appropriate power profile like *latency-performane* instead of *powersave*.

I also think, a lot of what you are asking, is answered more by choosing optimal hardware to run on more so than *tuning* linux.  The Linux operating system will inherently *disk cache* and do exactly what I mentioned above with `tmpfs` in that it will operate as much as it can in RAM before having to write/flush to actual disk.  Which is simply saying if you want better performance, increase your RAM - if you are running only 8 or 16gb on a pc then update it to 64gb or higher; likewise with servers if it's < 128gb then max it to 768gb or better, along with fastest RAM DIMM timings supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.